# How do I reinstall wine?

Tags: wine

On my ubuntu 17.10 fresh install I tried to install wine staging. It ended up with an error and apps that supposed to work fine doesn't work at all. How do I reinstall wine to stable version? I tried

`wine apt-get --remove purge wine`

```
sudo apt-get --remove purge winehq-staging
```

and then

```
sudo apt install winehq-stable
```

Nothing worked so far. Seems I'm unable to remove wine first.

Edit. Errors:

```
pkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-s9gNMn/39-libsane1_1.0.27-1~experimental2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-sane.hwdb', which is different from other instances of package libsane1:i386

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-s9gNMn/39-libsane1_1.0.27-1~experimental2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: please include the terminal output showing the error you are receiving. PS try `apt-get` instead of `apt` I'm not sure if the command is correct for `apt`

Comment: edited. Result of sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable

Comment: we need a little more before this to see the actual error.

Comment: The full output is long to post. I found the error though pkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-s9gNMn/39-libsane1_1.0.27-1~experimental2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-sane.hwdb', which is different from other instances of package libsane1:i386